# What does it mean when it is said that faith is given by the Holy Spirit? (1 Cor. 12:9)

Tags: 1-corinthians, pneumatology, faith

1 Corinthians 12:9 ([KJV](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&x=0&y=0&b=1Cr&c=12&v=11#conc/9))

> To another faith by the same Spirit; to another the gifts of healing by the same Spirit;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seem like a simple answer but this section is talking about extra ordinary gifts.  **It is an unusual gift of faith to some believers only, not general faith in Christ.**  What these gifts were exactly and if they are still given today is a controversy within Christianity.  Primarily the split is between charismatics and tradition cessation movements.

For my own part I think this gift was and is a unusual surge of faith in a believer to believe the gospel in an unusual manner where the requirement is great and needy for a situation.  For example, Martin Luther must have had this gift to stand almost alone fully relying on salvation apart from works while the established church called him an accursed heretic.  This was an unusual faith that benefited the church at large. It was an extra ordinary gift given by the Spirit on Luther.

Many of the early believers in Acts seemed to have this gift, especially those faithful while being martyred. Similarity when David killed Goliath, or Samson slew the Philistines, it would seem they had unusual faith given to them. Although not possessing them against their wills like Devils, the Holy Spirit can surge through willing vessels, where faith is needed, in remarkable ways.

Answer (score 1):

The spiritual gift of Faith is significant as Ellicott observes:

> **Faith**.—This cannot mean the faith which is necessary to salvation, for that belongs to all Christians; but such faith as is mentioned in
> Matthew 17:20, Luke 17:6, the results of such a faith being here
> enlarged, and not embracing miracles alone, but prophecy and the
> discerning of spirits. In the Greek “the word of wisdom” is said to be
> given by the Spirit; “the word of knowledge “according to the Spirit;
> and “the faith and gift of healing” in the Spirit. By the use of this
> variety of expression the Apostle probably means to indicate the
> variety of methods of operation of the Spirit, as well as the
> diversity of the gifts which He lavishes.

Similarly, the Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary observes:

> 9. faith—not of doctrines, but of miracles: confidence in God, by the impulse of His Spirit, that He would enable them to perform any
>    required miracle (compare 1Co 13:2; Mr 11:23; Jas 5:15). Its nature,
>    or principle, is the same as that of saving faith, namely, reliance on
>    God; the producing cause, also, in the same,' namely, a power
>    altogether supernatural (Eph 1:19, 20). But the objects of faith
>    differ respectively. Hence, we see, saving faith does not save by its
>    instrinsic merit, but by the merits of Him who is the object of it.